# How to compare two matrices (numpy ndarrays) element by element and get the min-value of each comparison

Tags: python, numpy

So i want to make a comparison between two matrices (size: 98000 x 64). The comparison should be done element by element and i want to the min value of each comparison stored in a third matrix with the same dimensions. I also want the comparison being done without the use of loops!

Here's a small example:

```
a=np.array([1,2,3])
b=np.array([4,1,2])
```

a function that compares the 1 and the 4, the 2 and the 1 and the 3 and the 2 and stores it in the vector c

answer

```
c=[1,1,2]
```

is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numpy has a minimum feature, as below:

```
c = np.minimum(a,b)
```